# JBPM : POST request for execute process go wrong

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I am new to jBPM.

I reference [jbpm.org](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.14.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/index.html#_business_application_with_custom_work_item_handlers_and_event_listeners) for tutorial. And I tried "**My First Business Application**" example. It is OK.

And then I tried the next tutorial "**Business Application with Business Asset**". The first steps are going well. I successfully done installation of jBPM Console, drawing business process asset in KIE process and starting the application are going well.

And I tested according to reference. I got a problem for sending POST request to my application. I use Chrome Postman client for sending POST request.

In tutorial, they give the following link to make POST request.

```
http://localhost:8090/rest/server/containers/business-application-kjar/processes/business-application-kjar.process/instances
```

I do but I always get "**415 Unsupported Media Type**" in every time. I also research for error. I can't find anywhere.

Please help me.

I am trouble for continue the next examples.

I want to know is any way to continue or am I wrong in sending request.

[image: Postman]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**415 - Unsupported Media Type** error occurs when the request is in a format not supported by the server.

Add the following http header parameters to your request.

```
Accept: application/json

Content-type: application/json

X-KIE-ContentType: JSON
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. Can you show me detail or any picture reference. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a simple json body to the request and try?

Comment: Any reason why Content-type is application/octet-stream instead of application/json (in your postman screenshot)?

Comment: Thanks...Content-type is error. I fixed and it is working.